# Is there a python equivalent of fortran repeatable format descriptors?

Tags: python, fortran, string-formatting

In fortran string formatting, the last format descriptor is repeated indefinitely. And the same format can be used for both writing and parsing.

Is it possible to replicate this formatting for writing/parsing in python?

If a specific example helps, what would be the python equivalent of this fortran format?

```
"(f5.2,10(f8.3))"
```

I would expect something like this:

```
"{:5.2f}??".format(*args)
```

Comment: Can you give an output example?

Comment: Python's format strings are for writing (i.e., converting values to a string), not reading (parsing a string into values). How were you intending to use them for reading?

Comment: The wording is a little confusing.  Are you trying to format a list of up to 5 items, or are you trying to parse a string?

Comment: I would use regex.  ```re.findall(pattern, string)``` would return a list of matching outputs, you can just assign some logic to check the length of that list.

Comment: I believe the best route is to go with regular expressions and grab the first 5 results, if I am understanding correctly.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I was going to use the parse library since it was made to be the opposite of the .format() method. I reformulated the question to show what I am used to in fortran and can't seem to be able to reproduce in python

Comment: @Seb: That's definitely information that should go in the question. The `parse` library is not part of the Python standard library, and it's not that well known in the Python community, so it's far from obvious that that's what you were intending to use.

Comment: @MarkDickinson The question is now only about the possibility of reproducing in python the fortran formatting presented. I would prefer if it was possible in standard python. I don't want to have what I intended to use part of the question because I have no idea if that is the correct use.

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If yes, please mark the best answer as accepted.

Comment: @fferri no the current answers address the question before it was marked as unclear and put on hold. The question has changed quite a bit after that, I would have preferred to be able to delete it and re-ask it properly but that's apparently not possible ...

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, you can generate the pattern based on the number of values you have.

Since your `'{:2d} {:5.2f}'` pattern needs two values, I will divide the number of repetition by two:

```
pattern = ' '.join(['{:2d} {:5.2f}'] * (len(my_values) // 2))
result = pattern.format(*my_values)
```

Comment: I was going to provide a small function to do that, but your approach is simpler and I would probably prefer to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own function to handle a repeated format string:

```
def format_up_to(n, fmt, fmt_len, *args):
    args0, extra_args = args[:fmt_len], args[fmt_len:]
    if not args0: return ''
    if n <= 0: raise Exception('extra arguments: {}'.format(args))
    return fmt.format(*args0) + format_up_to(n-1, fmt, fmt_len, *extra_args)
```

the arguments are the maximum number of repetitions, the format string, the number of items in the format string, and then any number of arguments that will be formatted:

```
print(format_up_to(5, ' {:2d} {:5.2f}', 2, 1, 2))
```

gives you:

> 1  2.00

```
print(format_up_to(5, ' {:2d} {:5.2f}', 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

gives you:

> 1  2.00  3  4.00  5  6.00  7  8.00  9 10.00

```
print(format_up_to(5, ' {:2d} {:5.2f}', 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
```

gives you:

> Exception: extra arguments: (11, 12)